# Twitter bootstrap tooltip

Tags: twitter, html, bootstrap, javascript

Решил воспользоваться данной штучкой, возникла не большая проблема по плагину: http://bootstrap.veliovgroup.com/javascript.php#tooltips  (плагин подсказок).

Не могу его вызвать, в шаблоне в тэге `<head>` прописал следующий код:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bootstrap.veliovgroup.com/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"> </script>  
<script>$('#example').tooltip(options);</script>
```

Пути правильные, саму подсказку вызываю так:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>
```

Не работает, кто поправит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если с путями всё в порядке попробуйте:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>
```

в срипте я делал так:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').tooltip({
        selector: "[rel=tooltip]",
        placement: "bottom" 
    });
});
```

но у вас явные проблемы со знанием jQuery и js

Comment: Спасибо, не большие проблемы с jQuery и js есть, но я думал подсказки будут работать без дополнительных настроек, а просто по дефолту.

Comment: тултипы и поповеры - единственное к чему в Bootstrap не реализовано data-api